# Generate Time object given weekday and minutes since midnight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm trying to generate a Time object initialized to the next instance of a specific weekday and number of minutes past midnight.

My data (representing a schedule) looks like: weekday, start, finish. Weekday is the day of the week between 0 and 6, and start/finish are integers representing minutes past midnight on that particular weekday.

What I'd like to be able to do is get a Time object for the next time that this will be so that I can work more flexibly with the start/end times for frontend purposes.

Does anyone know how to do this? I've tinkered with Time.utc without much success.

Comment: How about showing some example dates and times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm interpreting this correctly... Is it where given a weekday, you will find the next available date that is on that weekday? For example, if today is tuesday, and your schedule is set for thursday, then the time object will be at midnight on this thursday? If that's the case, something like this should work:

```
day_difference = @weekday - Time.now.wday
# If the difference is in the past, then add 7 so that it is next week.
if day_difference < 0
  day_difference = day_difference + 7
end
next_date = Time.now.midnight + day_difference.days
start_time = next_date + @start.minutes
end_time = next_date + @finish.minutes
```

Where **weekday** is the value in your Schedule object. Once again, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. Here start_time and end_time are time objects representing the next weekday with the corresponding amount of minutes added to them.

Comment: This did the trick - total failure on my part to communicate properly, but you got the idea! I did use <code>if day_difference < 0 or (day_difference == 0 and self.start < ((Time.now.hour*60)+Time.now.min))</code> to go to the next time if it had already started.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something basic along these lines for this with something like the following:

```
class Schedule
  attr_accessor :day_of_week, :start_minute, :finish_minute

  def start(current_date = Time.zone.now)
    current_date.beginning_of_week + day_of_week.days + start_minute.minutes
  end

  def finish(current_date = Time.zone.now)
    current_date.beginning_of_week + day_of_week.days + finish_minute.minutes
  end

  def length
    (finish_minute - start_minute).minutes
  end
end
```

Since that's pretty rudimentary and I'm not sure exactly what you're looking to use it for, I suggest looking at some of the libraries mentioned in [this post](http://www.rubyinside.com/3-new-date-and-time-libraries-for-rubyists-3238.html) ice_cube, and business_time look like they're applicable for what you might be wanting

Comment: This wouldn't work in his case, since day_of_week corresponds to a day (ex: Tuesday = 2). If today is monday (1), then current_date + day_of_week.days would give 1+2, which is Wednesday. You'd need to take the difference to find the proper day.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add in `.beginning_of_week` thanks for catching that